# How to upload extension on magento connect?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.6, magento-connect

I have created a extension and want to upload on magento connect but when I upload it on magento connect it gives me following error:-

```
Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext...
```

I checked my extension which is working great on all versions.

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: How did you packed the extension?

Comment: You might want to refer to this article on packing extensions for Connect: http://markshust.com/2012/02/27/packaging-community-extension-distribution-magento-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.Actually package name should be same as your extension key name.In my case extension key at magento connect was "test_data" and package name in package.xml file was "Test_Data". I just change the package name and extension uploaded successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Verify informations of package and rename your extesion on admin Magento "Edit extension" for de name error code (key generate and show on painel of your extension in Connect).
Check the name of your package.xml too.